# jQuery Draggable - Scrolling containers other than its own with

Tags: jquery-ui, scroll, jquery-ui-draggable, horizontal-scrolling, jquery-ui-droppable

So I have an unordered list of draggables that I want to drag into another unordered list of droppables. If I clone the draggable and append it to "body", then I can drag it out of its container and drop it on the droppable elements in the other list, but it does not automatically scroll through the droppable unordered list. If I clone and append to the other unordered list, then it will automatically scroll the droppable list, but the element is not visible when dragging until it is hovering over the droppable list. Does anyone know of a workaround or a better approach to this problem?

Fiddle with code here: https://jsfiddle.net/bkfxjnom/6/
Draggable code:

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    appendTo: "body",
    zIndex: 100,
    refreshPositions: true,
    revert: 'invalid',
    start: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    },
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $(this).css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
  });
```

Droppable list html:

```
 <ul class="list-group" id="root" style="overflow-y:scroll; height: 150px">

    <li class="list-group-item category-droppable" id="level1">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>FirstLvL
      <ul class="list-group" id="level1">

        <li class="list-group-item category-droppable" id="level2">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>SecondLvL
          <ul class="list-group" id="level2">

            <li class="list-group-item category-droppable" name="A" id="level3">A</li>+++ many li elements

          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So the workaround I ended up using for this was to append the clone to the container I wanted to be scrollable, as well as containing it there. 
Then I made another clone that I offset on drag with the mouse, of which is positioned absolutely. Sort of a hacky solution, but it works.

```
                $('.draggable').draggable({
                    scrollSensitivity: 35,
                    scrollSpeed: 28,
                    containment: "#root",
                    helper: "clone",
                    appendTo: "#root",
                    zIndex: 5000,
                    refreshPositions: true,
                    start: function (event, ui) {
                        parent = $(this);
                        $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
                        $(ui.helper).css('visibility', 'hidden');
                        clone = $(this).clone();
                        clone.addClass("ui-draggable-dragging");
                        clone.css('visibility', 'visible');
                        clone.css("position", "absolute");
                        clone.css("z-index", 5001);
                        clone.prependTo($(".dragging-area"));
                        $("#unprocessed_list").droppable("disable");
                    },
                    stop: function (event, ui) {
                        clone.animate($(this).offset(), 500);
                        setTimeout(function () { clone.remove(); parent.css('visibility', 'visible'); }, 500);
                        $("#unprocessed_list").droppable("enable");

                    },
                    drag: function (event, ui) {
                        clone.offset({ top: event.pageY - clone.height(), left: event.pageX - clone.width()/2 });
                    }
                });
```